# Synchronised timely refresh of multiple divs

Tags: php, jquery

I have written a code to refresh two divs at regular intervals of time. Here it is

```
 <script language="javascript"> 
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $("#autorefresh_1").load("content1.php");
 var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
    $("#autorefresh_1").load("content1.php");
    }, 9000);

$("#autorefresh_2").load("content2.php");
var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
    $("#autorefresh_2").load("content2.php");
    }, 9000);

});
 </script>
```

Is there some other best way of writing this code? prehaps merging the two? Sorry for the simple question, I am new to jQuery.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would do it like so:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     var refresh = function () {
        $("#autorefresh_1").load("content1.php");
        $("#autorefresh_2").load("content2.php");
     }

     setInterval(refresh, 9000);
     refresh();
 });
```

Comment: +1 Seems to be the best solution, although you can simplify it by replacing `$(document).ready(` with just `$(` in this case.